# Parsing specificly named list in a .py file using python

Tags: python, parsing

I just want to check if there is any better way of doing this rather than using what i came up with.

The thing is that i need to parse a `.py` file, more precisely i have to look for a specific `list` named **id_list** that contains several `int` numbers. Numbers can be written in several formats.

For example:

`id_list = [123456, 789123, 456789]`

```
id_list = [    123456,
               789123,
               456789    ]

id_list = [    123456
               ,789123
               ,456789    ]
```

What i came up with works just fine, but for the sake of perfectionism i want to know if there is "smoother" way of doing so.

```
with open(filepath, 'rb') as input_file:
    parsed_string = ''
    start_flag = False
    start_parsing = False
    for line in input_file:
        if 'id_list' in line:
            id_detected = True
        if id_detected:
            for char in line:
                if char == '[':
                    start_parsing = True
                if start_parsing and char != '\n':
                    parsed_string += char
                if char == ']':
                    id_detected = False
                    start_parsing = False
                    break
```

After that has been done im just filtering `parsed_string`:

```
new_string = "".join(filter(lambda char: char.isdigit() or char == ',', parsed_string))
```

Which gets me string containing numbers and commas: `123456,789123,456789`

So to wrap this up, is there anything that i could improve?

Comment: Why not just import the file and access `id_list` directly?

Comment: What about `id_list = list()`?  Or `x = []` then `id_list = x`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not quite sure if i should do that because there are a lot of files that needs to be parsed, importing all of them at once wouldn't be a good idea i suppose.

Comment: How come? Could you give some more context? Do these things change frequently? How do they get into the Python files to begin with?

Comment: Basicly im adding a search option in environment, i can already search based on filenames, what im trying to do is to enable searching for files based on those numbers in list. For example, if i type 123456 in search box i get all files containing those numbers in `id_list`.

Comment: What environment? Again, where do those numbers come from? When and how do they change? Please [edit] the question so we don't waste time solving an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Also what problem are you looking to solve with your current code? *"is there anything that i could improve?"* is very broad, do you think something *needs* improving? What?

Comment: They are manually written inside the files. They do not change. I'm just trying to get those numbers out of the files and connecting them to respectable filenames.

Comment: If this is a one-time process, just use import and store a mapping in a more easily accessible format. Don't do it on every search, that's not efficient. It's not really clear why your output is a string, either; a list or set of IDs would be more usable, surely?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to solve:

```
import re

with open(filepath, 'rb') as input_file:
    text = input_file.read()
    match = re.search(r'id_list\s*=\s*\[(.*?)\]', text, flags=re.DOTALL)

    if match is None:
        print "Not found"

    else:
        id_list_str = match.group(1)
        id_list = map(int, id_list_str.split(','))
        print id_list
```

Comment: `eval` and `exec` should generally be avoided because they can be a security risk. For details, please see [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder. Instead, you can use the safer alternative: `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: Manually parsing the data is definitely much safer!

Answer (score 0):

just use `import` and `from`

If you don't want to import the whole python files just import the elements you need

example

```
from filename.py import id_list
```